# Upgrading to ASP.Net Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Upgrading from ASP.Net Core 1.X to 2.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/)

I have encountered the following doubts/questions:

**First: The metapackage**

Now with

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

We get all the reference needed in our projects. However I don't know if I should exclude the packages of `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web`

I have a **doubt** about these reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
```

I see that the **metapackage has included** this one: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version`

Should I exclude only that one and leave the other two ( `CodeGeneration.Design` 
 and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc`there?

**Second: Errors**

I'm gettint all sort of errors

[image]

[image]

First one says that the packages installed with the metapackage are not compatible with aspnetcore2.0 Anyone have experienced this? Any recomendations on how to deal with this?

Second gives this error message:

*The type or name of the 'EntityFrameworkCore' namespace does not exist in the 'Microsoft' namespace (are any assembly references missing?)*

Thanks in advance!

**Final**

This is how my csproj looks like atm:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
    <None Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-lumen.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-sand.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-sand.min.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\application-role-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\family-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\jquery-3.2.1.min.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\modal-action-store.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\populate-district.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\store-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\type-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\user-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\jquery.filtertable.min.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\machine-index.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker" Version="4.17.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS" Version="4.17.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.CommandLine" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802909/updating-to-asp-net-core-2-0-packages-are-not-compatible-with-netcoreapp2-0

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the NuGet package if you are using .NET Core:

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.All`

If you're using the .NET Framework, then [the process is different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/).

For .NET Framework, I recommend creating a new ASP.NET Core project using the normal Visual Studio 2017 template. This will give you the option to create an ASP.NET Core 2.0 project with .NET Framework and you can select the target version. Then, you will need to migrate your content in to the project. It's a manual process because the project file format is so different. Once that is done, you will get some compilation errors because classes have moved around in to new namespaces as so on. But, it's not too hard to get it working. This method ensures that you don't pull any junk NuGet packages with you as well. You will be on a clean slate.