# Updating to ASP.NET Core 2.0 - Packages are not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to update to NET Core 2.0 but I'm getting these errors on all the packages installed with the reference.

**The problem, maybe:**

I'm getting a reference to `netcoreapp1.0` in the output:

> The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.0 package is not compatible with **netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp, Version = v1.0).** The Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 2.0.0 package supports: netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp, Version = v2.0)
>   One or more packages are not compatible with .NETCoreApp, Version = v1.0.
>   Detection of detected package: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore from 2.1.1 to 2.0.0
>     Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (> = 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup (> = 2.0.0) -> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore (> = 2.1. 1)
>     Application (> = 1.0.0) -> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore (> = 2.0.0)

After that, I get this message for all the components:

> The Microsoft.AspNetCore.ANYPACKAGE 2.0.0 package is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp, Version = v2.0). The Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets 2.0.0 package supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard, Version = v2.0)

This is the manual:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

SDK Updated to 2.0:

[image]

This is my `csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
    <Content Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
    <None Remove="wwwroot\lib\kendo-ui-core\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-lumen.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-sand.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\css\bootstrap-sand.min.css" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\application-role-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\family-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\jquery-3.2.1.min.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\modal-action-store.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\populate-district.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\store-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\type-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\user-index.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\jquery.filtertable.min.js" />
    <Content Include="wwwroot\js\machine-index.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker" Version="4.17.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker.CSS" Version="4.17.45" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NuGet.CommandLine" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Edit: More info**

After compiling the solution I got this message:

> 1> CSC: error CS1703: Multiple assemblies with equivalent identity have been imported: 'C: \ Users \ user \ .nuget \ packages \ microsoft.netcore.app \ 2.0.0 \ ref \ netcoreapp2.0 \ System.ComponentModel.dll 'And' C: \ Users \ User \ .nuget \ packages \ system.componentmodel \ 4.3.0 \ ref \ netstandard1.0 \ System.ComponentModel.dll '. Remove one of the duplicate references.

Comment: what happens when you create a brand new .net core 2 project and then add EF to it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Solved it by ***updating*** **Visual Studio** to it's latest version (for me it was 15.3.3)

Also, make sure **SDK** is updated to version 2.0 and **NuGet** to its latest version.

Comment: SDK download link: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.0-download.md

Answer (score 39):

Also, this error can occur with an outdated version of nuget. Specifically, 4.0.0 exhibits this issue. Upgrading to 4.3.0 fixed the problem for me.

VSTS agents seem to use 4.0.0, so to work around this, there is a nuget version installer task which you can run as part of your build step to upgrade the version of nuget running in your build pipeline.

Comment: Adding this step, fixed it for me.

Comment: Can you add some detail on what the task is? I don't see it in TFS 2017.2.

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson add **NuGet Tool Installer** task and change **Version of NuGet.exe to install** on corresponding version.

Comment: On premises TFS 2017 has the same problem. The build agent uses NuGet 4.0.0 by default even though a higher NuGet version is being used in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

You should install the new version of SDK. There are many solutions for this issue in GitHub such as https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/1675